# Flutter calendar with loop text strings?

Tags: flutter, dart

is there any calendar tool that i can put a text string under every day?

Text string will be looped,
only the numbers will be repeated by schedule, The calendar is normal.
For example :
Sunday 1, Monday 2, Tuesday 3, Wednesday 4, Thursday 5.
Repeat the loop...

Friday 1, Saturday 2, Sunday 3, Monday 4, Tuesday 5
repeat : Wednesday 1 & so on...

The user will configure on what day he wants to put the 1 and then it will configure the loop text strings on the calendar

Thank you for your kind assistant

Comment: I don't know what you mean but making custom calendars in flutter is easy. I have made a couple of them. if you didn't find what you are looking for, make your own or modify one of the existing open-source calendars on Github.

Comment: I dont know how to tell you more details..